# Process Builder Criteria from Related List

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, flow, process-builder, visual-flows

Can field values on related records be used as criteria in `Process Builder`?

Example:

We have a custom object called `Affiliation__c` as a junction between `Account` & `Contact` objects. To create the junction we added the following two fields to the object:

- Master-Detail (`Account`) field
- Master-Detail (`Contact`) field

I need an automated process to complete a field update on an Affiliation record when all of the following conditions are met:

- A field on the Affiliation record is equal to a specific value
- A field on the related Account record is equal to a specific value
- A field on the related Contact record is equal to TRUE

Please note: the `Contact` and `Account` records that are joined via an `Affiliation` record are not always related to one another in the "traditional" `Contact.AccountId` relationship. We created this junction object to meet the need of a `Contact` being related to multiple `Account` records.

If this is not possible via `Process Builder`, any input regarding other potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Process Builder can only fire processes off of changes to the main object. If the Process could potentially be fired off of a change to an Account or a change to a Contact, you'll have to create the Process twice.

For the Contact process, it'll have to fire when the contact change is made and the contact's Account field matches the right criteria. The Account process is trickier. You'll probably have to create a Flow that runs when the Account field is changed, which can look for any contact that matches the Contact field criteria in question and performs the update where it's needed.

Please let me know if you have questions about specifics.